# Help - Make object transparent to reveal picture underneath

Tags: transparency

[image]

I would like to make a similar image but with my own photos and maybe play around with the shapes, not just triangles. Could anybody please help me by explaining how I can create this image in Photoshop. Basically a transparent shape which shows the image below while still keeping the top layer white. Thank you.

Comment: Look up [layer masks and vector masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html)

Comment: ...or [Clipping Mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/clipping-masks.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Illustrator or Affinity Photo or Affinity Designer to achieve this - in all cases it's masking - either clipping or layer masks depending upon software choice.